# How to have 2 different themes for each sales channel in Shopware 6?

Tags: templates, twig, themes, shopware

I have created 1 theme and assigned it to a sales channel - everything was fine then.

Then I created a second sales channel using a subdomain and then created a new theme for it as well.

When I assign the theme to this 2nd sales channel I see that the template changes are applied to both sales channel storefronts. However scss files work logically.
So how to create the twig files (directory structure) so they will only affect the corresponding sales channel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a known bug in Shopware 6.2 and it is fixed not in the final release.

Not fixed in the release candidate 1 (SW6.2 RC1), but is fixed in the stable release.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the same in Shopware 6.2? It should be fixed there

Comment: Yes, I also wrote to the support during this time and they said that it should be fixed in the 6.2 and it is fixed indeed.